# Several Services exporting the same COM component

Tags: c++, windows, com, service

According to this article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809975.aspx
you can export a component in a service.

But is it possible to create several services that export different instance of the same component?

I see one potential issue is when defining the \HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AppID\\LocalService, since each service have different name I can't have them all in the same key.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite explicitly mentioned in the linked article:

> Do not use REGCLS_SINGLEUSE.
>   Registration fails if you use this
>   flag. The operating system allows a
>   single instance of a service. For this
>   reason, the COM component must be
>   available to multiple clients
>   simultaneously.

You *have* to use a regular out-of-process server if you want multiple instances of it.

Comment: Erm, okay, how did work out?  Key point of the quote is that you can get a service only started once.

Comment: What I did is: CoGetClassObject(MyCLSID CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, NULL, IID_IClassFactory, (PVOID*)&pCF); and later CoRegisterClassObject(MyCLSID, pCF, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, REGCLS_MULTIPLEUSE|REGCLS_MULTI_SEPARATE, &m_ckClassObj);

Comment: I have install the service with 2 differents name and it work but at some point I have a error: `The class is configured to run as a security id different from the caller`. Then I rename the \HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AppID\{CLSID}\LocalService to the name of the first service, start it and rerename it to the name of the second service and start the 2nd service and it works.

Comment: You're kinda on your own with these kind of hacks.  Hard to see how two services can do a better job than one.  Without you giving any rationale, there is no good way to give a better answer.

Comment: Is just a stability issue when on service crash the other remain since both services do mutual exclusive job it should not be a problem. Having all job running on the same service make it fragile, if one jobs hangs everything goes down.

Comment: This is a very strange approach.  I've got two cars.  When one of them breaks down, I'm still stuck in the middle of nowhere.  That other car doesn't help me get home.

Comment: Your metaphor does not apply to the situation. Is more like if you are selling cheese and you have 2 cheese factory. If one break down you can still sell cheese in a lesser quantities. (Tangent: That is why I don't really like metaphor sometime, they make people think that there argument is strong but in fact not carefully chosen a metaphor failed the point). But ok, if the bottom line is that we can't do it that is fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

[You can have multiple instances of the same service export a single different instance of the same component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897936/is-it-possible-to-have-an-out-of-process-com-server-where-a-separate-o-s-process).

Comment: No, that doesn't talk about a service.

Comment: D'oh, you are right.  I was only thinking in general of a local server, not specifically a Win32 service.