# How to make COM spawn a separate out-of-process server for each instance?

Tags: windows, com

I've got a server application that uses an external COM component, and it appears to be leaking memory.  I don't have the source to this component, or any way to debug or modify it, and after enough time it brings the server to its knees.

I'd like to move the COM functionality out-of-process, which isn't difficult (pass `CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER` and not `CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER` to `CoCreateInstance`) but there's one problem with that: the server is creating multiple instances of the COM object from different threads, with the timing such that it's possible that there could end up not being a point where there are 0 instances active for long enough to leak enough memory to crash the out-of-process host.

The obvious solution is to make it so that each `CoCreateInstance` spawns its own out-of-process server.  But all the resources I've seen on that, [including one question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897936/is-it-possible-to-have-an-out-of-process-com-server-where-a-separate-o-s-process), seem to require you to have access to the source of the DLL that is creating the COM object.  That's not the case here.

So is there any way to make each call to `CoCreateInstance` spawn a new out-of-process surrogate, when the only thing you are able to change is the code of the program that's calling `CoCreateInstance`?

(No C++ template library-based solutions, please, as the server in question is written in Delphi.)

Comment: So you got a chunk of software that you didn't write, don't have the source code for, can't debug, and it is misbehaving.  Pick up the phone, find the developer.  Talk to him.  I recommend a top-less service with an unlimited beer credit account to have him see it your way.  He'll be your friend and ask you to help out.  We can't do this for you.

Comment: @Hans: Long story short: that's more or less how I would handle it if possible, but that's kind of difficult when "the developer" is Microsoft.

Comment: That has to be flaw number one, nobody could have guessed that from the question.  I have to recommend the dancing girls.  Phone works too, call Microsoft Support.

Comment: @Hans: I didn't put that in the question because it's not relevant.  And have you ever actually tried working with Microsoft Support?  I have, and it's like filing a claim with an insurance company: anything they can possibly do to avoid having to actually help you, they will do.

Comment: Yes, I did.  Second time, I figured out what went wrong the first time.  Took 6 weeks but I got the solution I needed.  I got them to pay attention and got a dedicated engineer to look at my code (I uploaded it).  He grumbled and huffed, a bit, it took two weeks of his life.  But he sorted it out and told me how to work around the bug.  It worked well, it solved the problem.  Didn't cost me a dime, they refunded the charge.  You can do that too, it does require getting it started, all by yourself.

Comment: @Hans: Yeah, I've been down that road. I got a "dedicated engineer" too: a barely-intelligible guy with a thick Indian accent who kept asking me to do nonsensical things to "test my code" even though the very first thing I did when submitting the bug report was to provide a simple, minimalistic sample program that reproduces the bug 100% of the time, even on their system.  (And the second thing I did was make them verify that yes, it does reproduce the bug on their end!)  That's about the point where I realized they were actively trying to get me to go away.

Comment: Are you convinced that the way you documented your question allows anybody to help you sort out the problem?  Not so sure, but certainly somebody in Bangalore will sympathize.

Comment: Could you wrap the offending COM server inside your own COM server, so that you can use the solution you reference?